# MongoDB verify if fsync is working

Tags: perl, mongodb, disk, fsync

I perform fsync() operation in MongoDB, but it just returns immediately. It doesn't appear to have done anything. How do I verify if the data has indeed been flushed to disk at all?

NOTE: I set syncdelay to 0 which means that the writes won't be automatically fsync'ed every 60 seconds.

my actual command is using the perl driver:

```
$connection->fsync({async=>1});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the `fsync` to return immediately, then you can remove the `async` option and it will become a blocking operation.

But if you don't want it to be blocking, you can use [db.currentOp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp) from the shell to query the current state of the fsync.

If you want to get that information from Perl, you can use the technique I outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14766042/20745). Unfortunately there's no convenient way to get it directly via `run_command`.

Comment: Ok that is perfect! Thank you. Would syncdelay being set to 0 affect this operation? and does journalling have to be enabled for this?

Comment: syncdelay specifies the interval between automatic fsyncs; it doesn't affect what happens if you do a fsync manually. Journaling is not related to fsyncs.